# C# Error the type or namespace

Tags: c#, serial-port, openfiledialog

I get this error

> Error 2   The type or namespace name 'StringList' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

This is my source code:

```
try
 {
      StringList list = new StringList().FromFile("...Filename...");
      // Read list:);
      foreach (String line in list)
      {
            // .....
      }
}
```

I want to open a textfile and send i trough the comport but i got the error above.

Comment: Realy? What is `StringList` anyway?

Comment: Are you including the namespace:  `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities`?  (It's the only `StringList` I could find reference to...)

Comment: There *are* some `StringList` classes - but I doubt they're the ones you're thinking of.

Comment: I first thought this [StringList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.build.workflow.activities.stringlist.aspx) but the `FromFile` doesn't make sense, hope you didn't mean `List<string>`

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.build.workflow.activities.stringlist.aspx, IF you really want to use this, just google, click on the first msdn link and check what assembly and namespace you need.

Comment: Are u sure u included microsoft teamfoundation assemblies? StringList inherits from List<String>, try to use that instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just means that this class `StringList` is not referenced properly in your project. Make sure that you include the reference to `StringList`.

Find where this class belongs (could be a binary file, another project, other .NET references). And add that project/binary file to your reference by doing [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/wkze6zky.aspx).

Some were saying that you should add reference to `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities`. But there is also a possibility that you are not using this one. Bottomline is that you should just reference that namespace where that class belongs to properly.

Also I would like to add that referencing `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities` just to use `StringList` would be overkill and a waste. Only add references to namespaces that you truly need.

**EDIT:**

Okay so the OP just needs to read lines of string from the text file and put it in a list. What you can do is:

```
        List<string> listOfStringFromYourFile = new List<string>();
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("yourtextfile.txt", FileMode.Open))
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs))
            {
                listOfStringFromYourFile.Add(sr.ReadLine());
            }
        }
        //now you can traverse to your listOfStringFromYourFile either through foreach or whatever you like.
```

And don't forget to put `using System.IO;` before your namespace.

Comment: How do you know it's a "custom class"?

Comment: When I say custom class, it doesn't belong to BCL.

Comment: @DonBoitnott let me throw the question back at you, how do you know its `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities`?

Comment: Im not using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.Activities. But i cant seem to find the problem

Comment: @00Koornstra only you can determine where that `StringList` came from. If you can see the `using` directives usually found above your file, look if all these namespaces are referenced properly in your project.

Comment: I only suggested that it's the only `StringList` I could find...and I _didn't_ make it an answer.  Because it's a wild guess.

Comment: @DonBoitnott this is an answer. it's a tip on how to properly resolve this issue. this issue will never be directly resolved unless you pin-point where that class belongs to.

Comment: That's what comments are for.

Comment: @00Koornstra where did you get that source code? was it provided to you? what is your actual intent?

Comment: aiapatag i got it from my fellow worker but he's already left the office.

Comment: then what is your intent? does that StringList just represent a list of strings?

Comment: It hes to read out the txt file i selected and set the shole content in a list so i can send in over the comport

Comment: @00Koornstra you need to read line per line of the text file?

Comment: Yes its the easiest way, but if you have an other idea i would like to know.

Comment: @00Koornstra press refresh.

Comment: @00Koornstra np. although i would suggest that if you're gonna use StackOverflow again, you might want to read [Ask] first before asking so you can get a lot more positive responses from the members. :) happy coding!